# VBA is skipping code when a userform reference is reached? Attempting to write to another wbk

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I'm using a userform to collect data and add it to an empty line in a workbook.
Structure of code is as follows:

1. Main sub `s_OpenWriteToTargetFile` is called from userform `mainForm`.
2. It checks availability of the target workbook.
3. It opens the target workbook.
4. It calls sub "*s_WriteLines*". Everything is OK up to this point.
5. Sub `s_WriteLines` should load textbox values from `mainForm` into various variables and paste them into the target workbook.

For some reason, code execution jumps out of `s_WriteLines` as soon as it reaches `With MainForm...`, and it returns to the mother sub.

**s_WriteLines sub**

```
Sub s_WriteLines  
    Dim a,b as integer    

    With mainForm    
        a = .tb_a.Value    
        b = .tb_b.Value    
    End With    
End Sub
```

I can't wrap my head around it. Does this have something to do with the modality of the userform?

Comment: tried to check if the values in both tb_a & tb_b are integers?

Comment: @RomcelGeluz  Yes, I double checked. I ran the code step by step and it doesn't even get into  "with mainform...". Code above the "with mainform" will run ok.

Comment: just a note (not the solution): `Dim a,b as integer` only declares `b As Integer` but leaves `a As Variant` you need to specify a type for **every** variable.

Comment: tried passing the mainForm into a variable as Object type? Like, `Dim objThis as object: set objThis = mainForm`.

Comment: I would suspect an unfortunate combination of having an `On Error Resume Next` somewhere in the caller module AND not having mainForm as a valid object. Put this before `With mainForm` to check: `On Error Goto 0 : Debug.Print mainForm.Caption`

Comment: do you have any code in userform_intialize event?

Comment: What happens if you open the UserForm and hit F5 to run it?  (i.e. Is there an error in the Initialise `UserForm_Initialize` event?)  Also, you're not `.Show`ing your UserForm?

Answer (score 1):

As AcsErno suggested in the comments, there was a `on error resume next` that I didn't notice, and it kept me from learning that the form is failing to load a `rowsource` property of a combobox.

The `rowsource` was specified as follows:
`mainForm.cb_Wiresize.RowSource = wiresizesWSheet.Name & "!" & wiresizesFinalRange.Address`

The workbook that is opened to be written in also becomes active, and then the range that I specified as rowsource refers to a worksheet that doesn't exist - because I specified it only as "worksheet + range", instead of "workbook + worksheet + range".

To expand on my question, how can I refer to the specific workbook object using the syntax posted above? I tried different formulations but none worked.

Comment: Using `On Error Resume Next` without a proper error handling is always a very bad idea. Because it make you blind for errors but it does not prevent you from errors it just hides them.